# Android WebView inconsistent when activity is in the background

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-chrome, android-webview

I am using a WebView to receive Google Cloud channel messages using JavaScript (see code below). The WebView is hosted in the Activity that is used during sign-on, which is then kept in the background.

compileSdkVersion < 19 (always uses Android's WebView) -> JavaScript keeps running and receives events even though the Activity is in the background.

compileSdkVersion >= 19 (uses Chrome-based WebView) -> On a suitable device with SDK >= 19, JavaScript also keeps running and receives events even though the Activity is in the background, *BUT* on older devices SDK < 19, no events are received as soon another Activity is started.

Even though Google has announced http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-why-we-wont-patch-pre-kitkat-android-webview/ not to fix WebView's XSS vulnerability on older devices, it looks to me as if Google *is* messing with older devices when compileSdkVersion is set to 19 or higher. Older devices seem to run in some sort of compatibility mode, which does not seem to be compatible with expected behaviour. Google talks about upgrading WebView https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html, but does not mention that WebView behaves differently on older devices. And I also don't believe this is on purpose. I read Google made further changes in Lollypop, but I don't have a device which I could use for testing.

In other words, a big inconsistent beta mess which we all have expected in Android. Anybody has WebView working in the background on older devices with compileSdkVersion >= 19 or knows a workaround?

Here's the html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='{{ channelurl }}jsapi'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>WebView for ChannelService</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            onOpen = function() {
                ChannelListener.onOpen();
            };
            onMessage = function(message) {
                ChannelListener.onMessage(message.data);
            };
            onError = function(error) {
                ChannelListener.onError(error.code, error.description);
            };
            onClose = function() {
                ChannelListener.onClose();
            };

            var token = '{{ token }}';
            var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);

            var handler = {
                'onopen': onOpen,
                'onmessage': onMessage,
                'onerror': onError,
                'onclose': onClose
            };

            var socket = channel.open(handler);

            socket.onopen = onOpen;
            socket.onmessage = onMessage;
            socket.onerror = onError;
            socket.onclose = onClose;

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the associated Java code:

```
public class ChannelService {

    private class ChannelListenerJavascriptInterface { // receive channel message from App Engine
        @JavascriptInterface public void onOpen() {
            requestOpen();
        }
        @JavascriptInterface public void onMessage(String message) {
            requestMessage(message);
        }
        @JavascriptInterface public void onError(Integer code, String description) {
            requestError(code, description);
        }
        @JavascriptInterface public void onClose() {
            requestClose();
        }
    }



    public ChannelService() throws IOException { // use a hidden WebView to host JavaScript code
        if (Session.exists()) {

            final Activity activity = (Activity) Session.getContext(); // retrieve the activity context in which the web view is hosted

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { // ensure WebView is running on UI thread
                @Override public void run() {

                    WebView webView = (WebView) activity.findViewById(R.id.channel_webview); // listen to remote channel while Session exists; otherwise only to local channels

                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new ChannelListenerJavascriptInterface(), "ChannelListener");

                    String html = null;
                    try {
                        html = AssetsHelper.assetToString(Session.getContext(), "channel.html");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot read assets/channel.html file.", e);
                    }

                    html = html.replaceAll("\\{\\{ channelurl \\}\\}", MobileService.getChannelEndpoint());
                    html = html.replaceAll("\\{\\{ token \\}\\}", Session.getId());

                    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

                }
            });

        }
    }

    // Callback
    private OnMessageListener onMessageListener; public void setOnMessageListener(OnMessageListener onMessageListener) { this.onMessageListener = onMessageListener; }
    public interface OnMessageListener {
        public void onOpen();
        public void onMessage(String message);
        public void onClose();
        public void onError(Integer errorCode, String description);
    }

    private void requestOpen() {
        if(onMessageListener != null) { onMessageListener.onOpen(); }
    }
    private void requestMessage(String message) {
        if(onMessageListener != null) { onMessageListener.onMessage(message); }
    }
    private void requestError(Integer code, String description) {
        if(onMessageListener != null) { onMessageListener.onError(code, description); }
    }
    private void requestClose() {
        if(onMessageListener != null) { onMessageListener.onClose(); }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Lollipop:

> I read Google made further changes in Lollypop, but I don't have a device which I could use for testing.

Our tests with Chromium-based WebView have indicated that App Engine Channel is not working for Android version 5.02 (Lollipop API level 21).

compileSdkVersion 22, buildToolsVersion "22.0.1", minSdkVersion 17, targetSdkVersion 22

The following issues have been raised:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172262

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=485749